# Eclipse always hangs on project build

Tags: 14.04, eclipse

I have tried hard to run a simple web project in my Eclipse Luna 64 bit version (which has web support) however every time I try to build my project it freezes and becomes unresponsive even at 3% and 7% of build.

My Ubuntu configurations are :
*14.04 LTS 
Intel® Core™ i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4
Intel® Ivybridge Mobile  Graphic 
64 bit OS*

I have also altered my eclipse ini file to allot more memory as :

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:PermSize=512M
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
```

Also I have disabled Automatic build. Please suggest what can I do more to solve this ?

Comment: There might be an error message in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory.

Comment: You may get better help with this over on [StackOverflow](//stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I uninstalled the Eclipse from my system completely and re-installed it. Its working okay for now , will check the logs in metadata next time when problem occurs . thanks anyways @greg-449